# Get facebook events graph api php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get an Facebook page events of user. I've checked that the app id and app secret are correct and I still keep getting the error. 
It shows empty array when i load the page

I'm new to the FB graph and having trouble getting a collection of Events associated with a Page. Is there any way to get a list of all the events created by a Page?

```
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );


use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
// start session
session_start();
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( '7345148733','ff76861be' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/get_friends.php');
// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
// create new session from saved access_token
$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
// validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
try {
if ( !$session->validate() ) {
$session = null;
}
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
// catch any exceptions
$session = null;
}
}
if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
// no session exists
try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
// When Facebook returns an error
// handle this better in production code
print_r( $ex );
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
// handle this better in production code
print_r( $ex );
}
}
// see if we have a session $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
// $session, 'GET', '/me/friends'
// ))->execute()->getGraphObject();
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
// save the session
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
// create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
$session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/events' );
$response = $request->execute();
// var_dump($response);
   // echo '<ul>';
    // foreach ($response["data"] as $value) {
        // echo '<li>';
        // echo '<div class="pic">';
        // echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/' . $value["id"] . '/picture"/>';
        // echo '</div>';
        // echo '<div class="picName">'.$value["name"].'</div>'; 
        // echo '</li>';
    // }
    // echo '</ul>';

// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
// print profile data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
// print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://localhost/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/src/get_friends.php') . '">Logout</a>';
} else {
// show login url
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_events' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
} 
 ?>
```

Comment: Not familiar with Events myself, but use the autoloader they provide instead of requiring each individual file yourself.

Comment: You're requesting user events, instead of page events as you write. What is your goal?

Comment: @Tobi i want to get events of user attending .

Comment: @TnCDeveloper Attending what? Please edit your quesiton so that your problem is understandable.